# What are the casualties from the Bonehead Maneuver?

Tags: babylon-5

How many ships or lives were lost trying to open a jumpgate inside a jumpgate - also known as the Bonehead Maneuver? Were any statistics documented?

Earth forces attempted this tactic during the Earth-Minbari war, and I think [it was used one additional time](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Matters_of_Honor) since then against the Shadows.

Comment: It doesn't need to have actually been attempted to be named - merely conceived as a possibility

Comment: That's still an answer if true